# android number dialog problems

Tags: android, dialog, numbers

I can use number (0,1,2,3,..,9) & clear, delete. But I can't use decimal. And then, when I delete, I don't want to delete all **.setText (" ")**, I want to delete one by one when user use 4 number (1234).

```
    edt_cargo_info_money_amount = (EditText) contentView.findViewById(R.id.edt_cargo_info_money_amount);
    Button[] numbers = new Button[11];
    numbers[0] = (Button) contentView.findViewById(R.id.one);
    numbers[1] = (Button) contentView.findViewById(R.id.two);
    numbers[2] = (Button) contentView.findViewById(R.id.three);
    numbers[3] = (Button) contentView.findViewById(R.id.four);
    numbers[4] = (Button) contentView.findViewById(R.id.five);
    numbers[5] = (Button) contentView.findViewById(R.id.six);
    numbers[6] = (Button) contentView.findViewById(R.id.seven);
    numbers[7] = (Button) contentView.findViewById(R.id.eight);
    numbers[8] = (Button) contentView.findViewById(R.id.nine);
    numbers[9] = (Button) contentView.findViewById(R.id.zero);
    numbers[10] = (Button) contentView.findViewById(R.id.decimal);
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        numbers[i].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                edt_cargo_info_money_amount.append(((Button) v).getText().toString());
            }
        });
    }
    del = (Button) contentView.findViewById(R.id.del);
    del.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            edt_cargo_info_money_amount.setText(" ");
        }
    });
    success = (Button) contentView.findViewById(R.id.ok);
    cancel = (Button) contentView.findViewById(R.id.cancel);
    success.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Amount = edt_cargo_info_money_amount.getText().length() > 0 ? edt_cargo_info_money_amount.getText().toString() : null;
            txt_display_money.setText(edt_cargo_info_money_amount.getText());
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            chk_cargo_info_money.setChecked(false);
            txt_display_money.setText("0.0");
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
```

Comment: call `setText("")` .Reduce extra Blank space first.

Comment: I have already do **setText (" ")**. setText means all clear; blank.. I don't want to clear all.

Comment: then Count total no and totalno-1

Comment: How to do that :D :D

Comment: Okay ,At first create a dummy Edittext and get edittext value using string .Then do my logic

Comment: please code show me :) I don't understand. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
String text = edt_cargo_info_money_amount.getText().toString();
edit_cargo_info_money_amount.setText(text.substring(0, text.length()-1);
```

substr(0, length-1) removes the last character, then we set the edit text to that new string.